# Подключение иконочных шрифтов в HTML письмо

Tags: html, css, email, шрифты, fontawesome

Подскажите как подключить иконки font awesome в html письмо. Единственный способ их подключения это скрипт, но как я понял html письмо скрипты не читает по какой то причине. Как быть в данной ситуации?

Comment: Не все почтовые клиенты понимают `@font-face`, лучше добавьте иконку изображением

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть сайт http://fa2png.io/, с помощью которого вы сможете сконвертировать иконку в png, и уже эту картинку вставить в письмо.

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно!